How to share a 64-bit integer from my kernel module to a userspace application?
I am using a signal handler to send an interrupt value to userspace before clearing the interrupt pin.
While clearing the interrupt pin, I read a register and try to send this value to the userspace process. I tried using signals but userspace cannot access kernel space memory.
How do I share a 64-bit integer from my kernel module to a userspace application?
// Prepare the siginfo_t structure
info.si_signo = SIGRTMIN; // Use a real-time signal
info.si_code = SI_QUEUE; // Indicate that this signal is sent using sigqueue
info.si_pid = current->pid; // PID of the sending process
info.si_uid = current->uid.val; // UID of the sending process

// Split the 64-bit value into two 32-bit parts
info.si_lower = (uint32_t)(value_to_send & 0xFFFFFFFF); // Lower 32 bits
info.si_upper = (uint32_t)(value_to_send >> 32); // Upper 32 bits
// Send the signal
if (send_sig_info(SIGRTMIN, &info, task) < 0) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "send_sig_info failed: %d\n", -1);
    return -1;
}


The user space process should be able to retrieve the value you’ve set via the siginfo structure - what seems to be the problem here?

all the fields in siginfo are only 32 bit size I want to send value which is 64 bit also I already using si_signo

also passing pointer si_value will not work because userspace cannot access kernel space memory

You might want to check the structure received by userspace before assuming you cannot access the fields in question. As far as I know, the kernel does not alter the structure. FWIW: si_int/si_ptr are user-supplied custom values that are not interpreted by the kernel at all during sigqueue, so they should work for your use case. If you are somehow unable to get what you want out of the userspace siginfo_t, update your question appropriately.

If the architecture uses 64-bit pointers, you can use si_ptr to store a 64-bit integer cast to void *. Unfortunately, that won't work if the architecture uses 32-bit pointers.

You can supply the value via sysfs and read it from userspace.

@IanAbbott, it won't even work on the cases when kernel is 64-bit and user space is 32-bit.
